# Lubuntu - terminal disappears but is still running

Tags: command-line, 18.04, lubuntu

I've added a quick launch section to my panel. I've added some programs and all are working fine so far except the terminal.

I have added the terminal to the quick launch. When I click on it, the terminal opens and I can run commands, etc.
But when I click outside the terminal window, for example on another app that is running, the terminal disappears and is nowhere to be found. It's still running but I can't get back to it.

I even tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> with no luck.

I know it's running because I have a script that I executed and then clicked outside the terminal window. I can tell by some file behavior that the script is still cranking away.

Comment: What terminal are you using? lxterminal?

Comment: There are 2 terminals available and I've tried both. I should also mention that if I open either terminal using the menus they work just fine. this is only happening when I launch it from quick launch.

Answer (score 1):

This bothered me a lot too. I was able to retrieve the QTerminal drop down by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.